# User is not authenticated

Tags: .net, silverlight, authentication, web-config

I have 2 Silverlight applications at the same hosting like:

> http://website.com/APP1
>
> http://website.com/APP2

I can login to each of them. But after this when I try to open any TAB/MENU/POPUP I am facing this error:

> User is not authenticated

I am guessing it is happeing because of the cookie and session.

Just in case I will put `web.config` parts...

```
  <authentication mode="Forms"  >
      <forms timeout="50000000"/> </authentication>
      <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15" cookieName="App2"/>
```

Any clue how to fix it?

Comment: Yes, prompt for re-authentication on particular events that require to be authenticated.

Comment: @GrantThomas But I don't need it. Those web sites are for different clients. How do I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok.. here is a solution . Just use different `name`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"  >
      <forms name="App1" timeout="50000000"/> </authentication>
```

And also we don't need

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="15" cookieName="App2"/>
```

Thas it!

Comment: All you've done is elongate the intervals at which this could happen.